# One class instance throw all controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i i have different class and controller.
and i need that one instance of model will be available in controller/
now i'm doing something like this:

```
def method1
    inst = @MyClass.new(params)
    inst.action
    ....
def method2
    inst = @MyClass.new(params)
    inst.action
    ....
```

but i want something like this

```
def method1    
     @inst.action
    ....
def method2
     @inst.action
```

or self.inst i't doesn't matter

how i can do it?

```
def self.inst
    MyClass.new(params)
end
```

doesn't work...

Comment: You need to start accepting the answers that are given to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a before_filter callback.

Heres how you use it

```
 class YourController < ApplicationController

   before_filter :find_resource 

   def action1
      @some_instance.magic
   end

   def action2
     @some_instance.magic
   end

  private
   def find_resource
      @some_instance = YourModel.find
   end

 end
```

You can also specify the actions that callback is run on with :only or :except options

HTH

Comment: thanks. i thought about this. but in this situation YourModel.find will be executed more that one time.. I search method to execute 1 time and use always.

Comment: the callback is called only once per request ( an action is also called once per request )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're confused about when to use instance variables.

In the first part of your code, you're saying

```
inst = @MyClass.new(params)
inst.action
```

This is grabbing the object stored in the instance variable `@MyClass`, calling `new` on it, and storing the result of *that* in the local variable `inst`.

But when you want to do `@inst.action` in the second set of code, you're relying on `@inst` being returned from a method `self.inst`, which is a method, not an instance variable.  Moreover, the `self.inst` method is no longer accessing the `@MyClass` instance variable -- it's accessing a constant named `MyClass`.

I *think* what you want, from what you've written, is:

```
def inst
  @MyClass.new(params) # access instance variable
end

def method1
  inst.action  # call a method that access the instance variable, then call `action` on that
  # or `self.inst.action` would be equivalent
  # ...
end
```

Comment: but as i can think @MyClass.new(params)  will be executing every time then i do 2inst.action" ?
i want only 1 .new(params) and only 1 variable per controller